# Array from a text file - using JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, file, text

I'm trying to make an array from CSV file. I wtore this but I don't knew how to finish it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java {

public static void main (String[] argv) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("1.txt");
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.printf(fileReader.nextLine());
    FileReader.close(); 
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I don't knew how to finish it

Comment: what do you have in "1.txt" . do you want to store each line in the file as an object in array ??? . I advice to use List instead of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read a CSV file in java

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class CsvFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            System.out.println("\n**** readLineByLineExample ****");
            String csvFilename = "C:/Users/hussain.a/Desktop/sample.csv";
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
            String[] col = null;
            while ((col = csvReader.readNext()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(col[0] );
                //System.out.println(col[0]);
            }
            csvReader.close();
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae)
        {
            System.out.println(ae+" : error here");
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("asd");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and you can get the related jar file from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/milyn/opencsv/1.6/opencsv-1.6.jar)

Comment: You're right opencsv would work, but for some reason the project seems to have lost steam. If the OP is comfortable adding third-party jars to the classpath, he/she can also consider Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv

Comment: @Vidya : yes ma'am , true story

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `fileReader.nextLine().split(",")` to create an array of Strings representing the comma-delimited items in the line.

Or you can use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fileReader.nextLine(), ",");
```

and then iterate through the tokens to get the comma-delimited items from the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Scanner s = null;
        List<String[]>  list  = new ArrayList<String[]>
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt")));

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String str = s.nextLine();
                list.add(str .split(","));
            }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }

list would have array of stings
```

Answer (score -1):

```
File f = new File(filepath)
BufferedReader b = new Bufferedreader(f.getInputStream);
String line = "";
String[] myArray = new String[100];
while((line = b.readLine())!=null)    // read file
{
     myArray[count++] = line;   // store in an array
}
```

Comment: Posting a working code is not an answer, please provide an explanation and point at the errors. (Of course that posting a not working code is not an answer too :)).

Comment: btw this code does not work, f.getInputStream, new String[100] <-- magic number? use List instead

Comment: The code is working fine, 100 is no magic number, but an assumption also we could even use linked lists but the OP mentioned array so..